# Test a list of string in a string, and return the value found if match

Tags: python, string, list

I have this list

```
list = ['DI', 'CI', 'CS', 'TQ','CE']
```

and a second list containing strings

```
list_string = ['dd4/DI/dew', '55t/ft54/CS/rgd/fge', '32g/tt/CE/45/543/g54', '454/533/633/76']
```

I would like to return a list, the same length as list_string, with the element in list, if it is present, if not return 'others', something like this

```
return_list = ['DI', 'CS', 'CE', 'others']
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I try this return_list = [next((t for t in item if list in t), "others")
       for item in list_string ], but the 'in' clause in the for does not take into account lists

Comment: @SimonBenavides, you might want to choose a name other than 'list', which might cause problem if your code needs, e.g., typecasting something to a Python list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my attempt:

```
list = ['DI', 'CI', 'CS', 'TQ', 'CE']

list_string = ['dd4/DI/dew',
               '55t/ft54/CS/rgd/fge',
               '32g/tt/CE/45/543/g54',
               '454/533/633/76']

return_list = [tuple(filter(lambda y: y in x, list))[0] if
    len(tuple(filter(lambda y: y in x, list))) else
    'others'
    for x in list_string]

print(return_list)
```

Here is the result, which is the same as your expected result:

```
['DI', 'CS', 'CE', 'others']
```

Comment: great! this works perfect! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want:

```
list = ['DI', 'CI', 'CS', 'TQ','CE']
list_string = ['dd4/DI/dew', '55t/ft54/CS/rgd/fge', '32g/tt/CE/45/543/g54', '454/533/633/76']

return_list = []
element_exists = False
for element in list:
    for word in list_string:
        if element in word:
            return_list.append(element)
        else:
            element_exists = False

if element_exists is False:
    return_list.append('others')
print(return_list)
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this, but the thing is that I have way to many values in my string list to do the comparison one by one

Comment: @SimonBenavides i cant think of a better way to do this considering the fact that you want to match a string from list A to a substring of list B. :(

Comment: @SimonBenavides i mean even if you dont use 2 for loops thats what will probably happen under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution using Regex, use `mylist` as the first list because `list` should not be a variable name:

```
import re

mylist = ['DI', 'CI', 'CS', 'TQ','CE']
list_string = ['dd4/DI/dew', '55t/ft54/CS/rgd/fge', '32g/tt/CE/45/543/g54', '454/533/633/76']

pat = '|'.join(re.escape(y) for y in mylist)
return_list = [''.join(re.findall(pat,x)) if re.search(pat,x) else 'others' for x in list_string]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this line for the comparison. This is the best one-line solution to your problem. But this will not return others. I'm currently working on the 'others' part.

```py
[j for i in list_string for j in i.split('/') if j in list]
#result
['DI', 'CS', 'CE']
```

You can also use this

```py
return [any([j in list for j in i.split('/')]) for i in list_string]
```

output for the given data is:

```py
[True, True, True, False]
```